# Foreach loop is repeating inside another foreach

Tags: php, loops

I have an array `$this->getcolumnname` which have 
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 1
            [Column_name] => Backlog
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 2
            [Column_name] => WIP
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 3
            [Column_name] => DOD
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 4
            [Column_name] => COMP
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 5
            [Column_name] => treat
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 6
            [Column_name] => asa
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [column_id] => 7
            [Column_name] => test
            [fk_sprint_id] => 1
            [fk_team_id] => 1
        )

)
```

and i have another Array `$this->getstories`

```
 Array
    (


[0] => Array
        (
            [i_description] => s2
            [Column_name] => Backlog
            [column_id] => 1
            [Tm_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [spid] => 1
            [fk_back_id] => 102
            [u_pos_is] => 1
            [s_id] => 6
            [color] => 2
            [_left] => 18
            [_top] => -9
            [wiptime] => 
            [dodtime] => 
            [Dep_status] => 0
        )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [i_description] => s1
                [Column_name] => WIP
                [column_id] => 2
                [Tm_id] => 0
                [name] => 
                [spid] => 1
                [fk_back_id] => 101
                [u_pos_is] => 2
                [s_id] => 5
                [color] => 2
                [_left] => 18
                [_top] => -9
                [wiptime] => 
                [dodtime] => 
                [Dep_status] => 0
            )

    )
```

And i have a foreach loop like

```
 foreach ($this->getcolumnname as $columnname):
         foreach ($this->getstories as $key => $restories) 
    <div class="panel-heading panel-bgwhite"><b><?php echo $columnname['Column_name'] ?></b>
    <p><?php echo $restories['i_description']; ?></p>

</div>
        endforech;
        endforeach;
```

i got result as double.actually count is 6 but i got 12 instead .My issue is foreach inside another foreach when i print the result it is increasing,ie value is repeating .

**Expected output:**

I want echo `'<pre>';print_r($columnname);` 6 times only.And `$restories` 2 times only.I want to print stories under respective column name .

Please help me.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? what is the __expected results__?

Comment: The outer foreach will loop 6 times (since `getcolumnname` contains 6 items). Then inside the first foreach, you iterate `getstories` which contains 2 items. So you'll iterate those two items 6 times. 6 * 2 = 12. What result are you expecting, and why do you even have the inner foreach? You're not using any data from it.

Comment: @u_mulder i have update my question..thanks for your reply

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have update my question,please help me...thanks for the reply

Comment: Just fyi, `$this->getcolumnname` contains 7 items, not 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple way you can do:

```
foreach ($this->getcolumnname as $columnname):
    echo '<pre>';print_r($columnname);
    foreach ($this->getstories as $restories):
        if ($columnname['Column_name'] === $restories['Column_name']):
            print_r($restories);
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i want to echo $columnname['column_name'] and under that column name i want to echo echo $restories['value'] correspond to each column ,if i did like this i cant get it.